# JodaTime LocalDate/LocalTime not Parsing with custom JSON Serializer classes

Tags: java, android, json, gson, jodatime

I have an object called `ReportEvent` which takes in a `LocalTime` as well as a `LocalDate` from the `JodaTime` API/framework. This `ReportEvent` is able to be written to `JSON` via google's `GSON` conversion API. However when deserializing the `JodaTime partial` causes problems.

Logcat Error Report:

```
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nanospark.cnc/com.nanospark.cnc.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "{"iChronology":{"iBase":{"iMinDa..."
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "{"iChronology":{"iBase":{"iMinDa..."
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:854)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDate(DateTimeFormatter.java:798)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.nanospark.cnc.LocalDateSerializer.deserialize(LocalDateSerializer.java:32)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.nanospark.cnc.LocalDateSerializer.deserialize(LocalDateSerializer.java:1)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:183)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:770)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:719)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.nanospark.cnc.GlobalData.retrieveGlobalDataFromStorage(GlobalData.java:118)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at com.nanospark.cnc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-16 13:23:01.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8884):     ... 11 more
```

Relevant sections of code:

LocalTime Serializer/Deserializer.

```
package com.nanospark.cnc;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;

import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;


public class LocalTimeSerializer implements JsonDeserializer<LocalTime>, JsonSerializer<LocalTime>
{

   private static final DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMAT = ISODateTimeFormat.timeNoMillis();

   @Override
   public LocalTime deserialize(final JsonElement je, final Type type,
                           final JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException
   {
      final String dateAsString = je.toString();
      if (je.isJsonNull() || dateAsString.length() == 0)
      {
         return null;
      }
      else
      {
         return TIME_FORMAT.parseLocalTime(dateAsString);         
      }
   }

   @Override
   public JsonElement serialize(final LocalTime src, final Type typeOfSrc,
                                final JsonSerializationContext context)
   {
      String retVal;
      if (src == null)
      {
         retVal = "";
      }
      else
      {
         retVal = TIME_FORMAT.print(src);
      }
      return new JsonPrimitive(retVal);
   }

}
```

LocalDate Serializer/Deserializer.

```
public class LocalDateSerializer implements JsonSerializer<LocalDate>, JsonDeserializer<LocalDate>
{

  private static final String PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd";
  final DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(PATTERN);


  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(LocalDate src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context)
  {
    String retVal = fmt.print(src);
    Log.v("MY LOCALDATE SERIALIZED", retVal);
    return new JsonPrimitive(retVal);
  }


  @Override
  public LocalDate deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException
  {

    Log.v("MY LOCALDATE DESERIALIZED",json.toString());
    return fmt.parseLocalDate(json.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287074/serializing-custom-object-that-contains-jodatime-objects-into-json another relevant question I posted.

Comment: Is the GSON/JSON bit actually relevant here, or could you reproduce the issue with a much simpler piece of code which just built a formatter and then parsed a hard-coded string? That would be a *lot* easier to help you with.

Comment: There is quite a bit of data that is handled by the `ReportEvent` object; but it seems to me that the sole issue lies with the JodaTime LocalDate/LocalTime being partial data and potentially calling the wrong constructor?

Comment: Possibly - so please perform appropriate diagnostic steps so that you can show this in about 5 lines of code instead of over 200. Basically, with the code you've provided it would be really hard to help you with this. If you can turn it into "I'm trying to parse *this* value like *this*, and it fails" then I suspect you'll get an answer much, much faster. (You haven't even shown the value you're trying to parse yet, as far as I can see. Log that first!)

Comment: Gotcha; let me take some time to write that up.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am attempting to extract the sharedPreferences from my DDMS view however I cannot seem to access Data folder. The reason being is I want to ensure I am using the exact string that was trying to be parsed.

Comment: Why don't you log it just before you try to parse it? That way you just need to add a single statement before the parse call...

Comment: Silly me, added the information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63189/discussion-between-tukajo-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: Um, those strings aren't even *slightly* the values that `ISODateFormat` is expecting to parse. It's expecting something like "2014-10-16".

Comment: As you can see by my imports on the serializing classes; I use JodaTime's specific `ISODateFormat`... You'd think it should be able to handle serialization of a JodaTime Object?

Comment: No, absolutely not. See my previous comment for what `ISODateFormat` is expecting to parse. Now look at your data. They're nothing like each other. That's a very odd representation of a date in JSON - I would *strongly* advise you to change your serialization code to make it output an ISO 8601  format date.

Comment: @JonSkeet I attempted to change the pattern and format for the pattern of yyyy-MM-dd as you can see by my updated code but for some reason I still get the same string as before? Shouldn't it serialize according to that pattern?

Comment: If it's going through the `serialize` code at all, then yes. You should check whether or not it actually is...

Comment: I do check; with a log. And that log does not print out. Sorry for the questions I am a bit new to serialization with Java. However; Would there be any reason why the serializer would not be called?

Comment: Well I have no idea where you're registering your serializers/deserializers... my *guess* is that that's the issue.

Comment: If that were the issue; why would deserialization work, (They are both in the same class that registered). I will add my registration code.

Comment: I've gone back to your first revision to see, and added an answer. Note that with logging and debugging, you should have been able to do quite a lot of this diagnostic work yourself... I haven't given much real input here, other than suggesting what diagnostics to do, none of which has been particularly insightful.

Comment: Yeah I agree; it was a dumb oversight and you definitely helped with the guidance of that. I will take what I learned into consideration for the future. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies with the code you've got that's serializing the data.

In your original question, you have this code when you're going to *deserialize* (`retrieveGlobalDataFromStorage`):

```
final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder()
   .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer())
   .registerTypeAdapter(LocalTime.class, new LocalTimeSerializer());
final Gson gson = builder.create();
```

But when you're going to *serialize* (`storeGlobalData`) you just have:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

You should be registering the type adapters in *both* places. I'd extract that code (`Gson` initialization) to a separate method which you can call from both your methods.

Answer (score 3):

It's also worth to be careful in `deserialize()` with

```
    return fmt.parseLocalDate(json.toString());
```

as it produces the likely unexpected quotation marks `""2014-10-28""`.

It may be better to use instead:

```
    return fmt.parseLocalDate(json.getAsString());
```

Comment: Yeah I had made the discovery later on. Good for others to know however.