# How to serialize Joda-Time's LocalDate with Kryo

Tags: java, jodatime, kryo

I am trying to serialize with Kryo a class containing a LocalDate from Joda-Time.

It looks like I'll need a custom-made serializer.

I found some Joda-Time serializers in https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers but none for LocalDate.

Any help? Should I write my own :(?

(Some people marked this as duplicate of [Serializing custom object that contains JodaTime objects into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287074/serializing-custom-object-that-contains-jodatime-objects-into-json), but this is a question about **existing Kyro serializers**, I fail to see how an answer about a custom JSON serializer solves my problem...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That repository you mention ([magro/kryo-serializers](https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers)) now does have a `JodaLocalDateSerializer` (and other Joda serializers) - since about June 2015, a couple of months after you asked.